# Unlink an ELF executable

Tags: gcc, reverse-engineering, ld, elf

Is it possible to unlink a dynamically linked ELF executable? I want to regenerate an object file (.o) from a final executable file without recompiling from source, and then relink it statically.

Comment: what are you doing? reverse engineering? hacking?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: https://stallman.org/articles/on-hacking.html ;)

Comment: @ArjunShankar: languages change and evolve. I feel it's a bit pointless arguing about what the *original* meaning was ;P

Comment: Just use the `unlink` system call ;)

Comment: @hobbs hahaha good joke :-p, but i want to preserve my file !

Comment: @KarolyHorvath i dont know if it's relevant for you, but i'm trying to run a Native Linux binary within Android system without dealing with LD_PRELOAD or LD_LIBRARY_PATH stuffs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are things such as [Ermine](http://magicermine.com/), [ELF Statifier](http://statifier.sourceforge.net/), and [jumpstart](http://bitwagon.com/jumpstart/jumpstart.html) for x86/x86_64.

[This feature comparison page](http://www.magicermine.com/products.html#feature_comparison) from Ermine nicely shows the capabilities of Ermine Pro/Lite vs. ELF Statifier.

Comment: good pointer for Ermine! thanks, i tested its Trial version on X86_64, and it works hope it works also for ARM.
I also get look at the open source 'statifier' mentioned on Ermine page, but it gives me "Segmentation fault" which i thinks due to no support for ASLR.

Comment: I'm not interesting on emulation (x86/x86_64 => ARM). I'm interesting on the concept of 'statisfiying' an elf executable in general. Can you please update your response to exclude this, that i can accept your answer.
By the way what are the others links you want to refers too ? (i think you can post them here as comments).

Comment: Glad to help! Edited the answer to include links. And yes, I do believe Statifier has a problem with ASLR.

Answer (score 1):

You can try your luck with WCC

https://github.com/endrazine/wcc

`$ wcc -c /bin/ls -o /tmp/ls.o`

Comment: Thanks for your response. wcc looks awesome from the documentation, I wasn't aware of that great tool. I'll give it a try.